# firebase - listening to changes automatically

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have ~10 users in my firebase database and I'd like to observe if some change happened. Earlier I observed the full database and when 5 users clicked submit on his cell phone at the same time it occured that the datas got mixed and that's how they got stored in the database. After that I wrote separate listener and seperate function for each user and this is how the listening happens:

```
def aer(post):
        handle_fiba_post(post, "go")


def ber(post):
        handle_fiba_post(post, "zi97")


def cer(post):
        handle_fiba_post(post, "ja7")

go_fa = db.child("cs").child("go").stream(aer)
zi97_fa = db.child("cs").child("zi97").stream(ber)
ja7_fa = db.child("cs").child("ja7").stream(cer)
```

Are there any ways I can handle each user seperately and listen them without getting wrong datas for wrong users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Listeners

- Listener will listen to any database changes in a particular path

#### Sample Code

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate("./firebase-admin-key.json")
print("initilising firebase database app")

#Initilising Database
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://<project-id>-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com'
})

print("Initialised firebase database app")

def listener(event):    
    def listener(event):    
    if(str(event.data)!="None"):
        print("________________________________________________")
        print("|----------------New Trigger L1-----------------|")
        print("________________________________________________\n") 
    else:
        print("Something Else Triggered...")
        print("_____________________________")
        print("\n")


def listener2(event):   
    def listener(event):    
    if(str(event.data)!="None"):
        print("________________________________________________")
        print("|----------------New Trigger L2-----------------|")
        print("________________________________________________\n") 
    else:
        print("Something Else Triggered...")
        print("_____________________________")
        print("\n") 


print("***********************************************")
print("* Connecting Listeners with the User  Data *")
listener = db.reference('cs').child("go").listen(listener)
listener2 = db.reference('cs').child("zi97").listen(listener2)
print("\n")
print("***********************************************")
```